# Multiple images upload carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rails-models

I have two models "Posts" and "Images" I wanted "Posts" to have multiple "Images" so I currently have it so "Posts" has many "Images" and "Images" belongs" to "Posts". I have carrierwave taking care of the file upload part, I am wondering if anyone knows how I can upload many images to the "Posts" model. So far I have tried using jquery-file-upload and keeping only the "Posts" model, but that just created many unassociated images that were of no use. I have also tried creating 2 models (as mentioned at the top) and having a nested form (following the [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1?view=similar)), and this just ended up not working I get the error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes". Anyway if anyone knows how or where I could learn how to add multiple images in that are associated to the "Posts" model, I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I finally figured it out. For anyone wondering how to do this I recommend reading https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/786

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
attr_accessible :images_attributes
```

into `Post` model in order to get rid of "Can't mass-assign protected attributes".

Comment: I have tried this but still getting the same error, I have read around and found out that their is a bug with carrierwave. However I have implemented their "fix" but when I enter <%= fields_for :post_images... the form no longer shows up. I have the "post_image" model relating to "Post" as so "belongs_to :pimages, polymorphic => true" and "Post", "  has_many :post_images, :as => :pimages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_images" THanks